# Rails Error messages with attributes regarding their genders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization, translation

I am writing a translation for my rails application (pt.yml) that trasnlates all activerecord error messages in portuguese.

```
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: Usuário
      feedback: Contato
  attributes:
    user:
      password: "senha"
      phone_number: "celular"
      first_name: "nome"
      last_name: "sobrenome"
      password_confirmation: "Confirmação de senha"
    feedback:
      title: "Título"
      name: "Nome"
      message: "Mensagem"
    report:
      before_photo: "A foto do foco"
  errors:
    template:
      header:
        one: "1 erro impediu que o %{model.model_name.human} fosse salvo"
        other: "%{count} erros impediram que o %{model}  fosse salvo"
    messages:
      blank: "é obrigatório."
      confirmation: "não confere."
      empty: "é obrigatório."
      exclusion: "está reservado."
      invalid: "não é válido."
      taken: "já está em uso."
      too_long: "é muito longo. (mínimo de %{count} caracteres)"
      too_short: "é muito curto. (mínimo de %{count} caracteres)"
      not_a_number: "não é um número."
```

The problem is that an attribute can be masculine or feminine and error messages should be dependent on their gender. For example, "é obrigatório or é obrigatória". Is there a simple solution to handle gender of attributes when we produce error messages?

Comment: I face the same problem and I don't think there's an easy way to do it. You can run your own validation methods and then add the error message according to the gender. Let me know if you find an better way to do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that I could use different error messages for each attribute of each models. config/locales/pt.yml would look something like this:

```
pt:
    activerecord:
        models:
            user: Usuário
        attributes:
            password: "Senha"
            first_name: "Nome"
        errors:
            models:
                user:
                    attributes:
                        password:
                            blank: "é obrigatória."
                        first_name:
                            blank: "é obrigatório."
```

So pt -> errors -> models -> #{model_name} -> attributes -> #{attribute_name} would specify the location for these custom gender-specific error messages for each attribute. Hope this could help anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

This is more a workaround than a proper solution to the problem, but if you're not too concerned, that might be a good tip for latin derived languages.

I also struggled trying to make the adjective match the gender of the attribute (a problem that doesn't exist in english), then I found out I should always reference the field:

```
Female attribute -> The field must not be blank
Male attribute -> The field must be whatever
```

In that way, you get a **DRY**er approach.

Specifically in the case of portuguese, mine goes:

```
  # ActiveRecord
  errors:
    messages:
      empty: "O campo é obrigatório."
      blank: "é campo obrigatório." # another idea
```